# Is there a small lcd display than can still be used with a camera?

Tags: hardware

I simply need to acquire a small lcd, in the range of 1 to 3 inches wide, that allows for the use of a camera.

Comment: How is this Pi related? And you are also being exceptionally vague

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there certainly are such lcd screens, both with and without touchscreen. [Adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com) is one supplier with a large selection, there are others too. They usually have a step-by-step tutorial for their products.